# Determining an expression for volume in terms of time, V(t).

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In the following derivation I am trying to determine an expression for volume in terms of time, V(t). I am given the equations. 
$$\triangle P = \frac{1}{2}\rho u^2$$
$$\triangle P = \rho g h$$
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = -ua$$
$$V(t) = Ah(t)+V_0$$

Combining the top $2$ equations and solving for $u$ yields,

$$u = \sqrt{2gh}$$

The initial condition of the problem is $V_0 = 50.$

Below are my workings but I am having problems determining $V(t)$.

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = - a \sqrt{2gh}$$
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = -a \sqrt{2g}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{V-V_o}{A}}$$
$$\frac{dV}{\sqrt{\frac{V-V_o}{A}}} = -a \sqrt{2g}dt$$

Is this correct for determining $V(t)$?

Comment: Looks fine, you could have left A on the right hand side of the equation, not that it matters. Now you just integrate and apply the initial condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good, as mentioned in the comment lets keep A on the right to make things simpler. This technique is called separation of variables. You will integrate the left side with respect to V and the right side with respect to t.

Starting with:

$$\frac{dV}{\sqrt{V-50}} = -a\sqrt{\frac{2g}{A}}dt$$

We integrate the right side with respect to $t$:

$$\int_{0}^t -a\sqrt{\frac{2g}{A}}dt = -at\ \sqrt{\frac{2g}{A}} $$

For the left hand side we will make the substitution

$w = \sqrt{V-V_0} = \sqrt{V-50} \implies V= w^2-50 \implies dV = 2w \ dW$

and get

$$\int_{50}^V \frac{dV}{\sqrt{V-50}} = \int_{w(50)}^{w(V)}2\ dw = \int_{0}^{\sqrt{V-50}} 2 \ dw = \left.2w\ \right|_0^{\sqrt{V-50}} = 2\sqrt{V-50}$$

Altogether,

$$ 2\sqrt{V-50} = -at\ \sqrt{\frac{2g}{A}}$$

$$4(V-50) = (a^2t^2)(\frac{2g}{A})$$

$$V-50 = \frac{(a^2t^2)(\frac{2g}{A})}{4}$$

$$ V = 50 + \frac{(a^2t^2)(\frac{2g}{A})}{4}$$

$$ V = 50 + \frac{a^2t^2g}{2A}$$

$$ V = \frac{100A + a^2t^2g}{2A}$$

Comment: thanks for your submission!

Comment: is $V_0$ the same as $V(0)$?

Comment: @user123 Yes, 50 in this case

Comment: could you finish this integration? I have been stuck for some time on the ending, thanks!

Comment: @user123 Done. Just solve for V now.

Comment: so $$V(t) = \frac{a^2gt^2+100a}{2A}$$ does this look correct to you?

Comment: @user123 Close. Needs to be 100A not 100a. See edit